# Capture header Location with JSOUP or other HTML PARSER

Tags: parsing, header, location, jsoup

When I'm picking up the response of a site with JSOUP, I can capture all headers except the LOCATION.

With JSOUP or some other html parser there some way to capture the value of the response header "LOCATION"?

Comment: Do you mean capture `Location` header field from HTTP response?

Comment: yes, it is. Location header field.

Comment: You cannot do that with an HTML parser. You need to read it from the HTTP response.

Comment: You mean this? -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: @jsalonen Could you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read Location with JSoup.

**Real example**

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup
        .connect("http://tvnwarszawa.pl/d")
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .followRedirects(false)
        .execute();

System.out.println(response.header("Location"));
```

**Output**

```
http://tvnwarszawa.tvn24.pl/d
```

Read more about Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Maybe you are interested in url()?

```
System.out.println(response.url());
```

Comment: Yes, I have tested. Result depends or geographical location :) I have other example.

Comment: Ok, Is this possible with POST method?